# Change data in OLE Unbound Excel worksheet in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an OLE UNBOUND object in one form, with a class Excel.Sheet.12
by clicking in it I can insert data as an Excel sheet, but now I want to fill some cells using information present in a table in the database (to keep updated the Oleunbound embedded excel sheet). 
I know how to manipulate external Excel files, but I don't know how to manipulate this excel object (e.g. what do I have to declare to select the right object?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat .Object property of its' control as Excel

```
Me.OLEUnboundControlNname.Object.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Here I am!"
```